# QGIS processing algortihm crashes in python console but works manualy

Tags: qgis, intersection, algorithm, qgis-python-console

I am loading two layers from PostGIS database and I am trying to run 'qgis:intersection' algorithm with them. Execution of the algorithm through the python console initially works but crash after 2-3%. Loading the layers through the console and then manually starting the algorithm works all the way though. I'm guessing that there is further processing of the layer that needs to be before putting them through the intersection algorithm. Here is an example of my script.

```
import processing

sql1 = "select system, gid, surface, st_collectionextract(st_makevalid(geom),3)::geometry(MultiPolygon, 3047) as geom from dobrich_ias_final"

uri1 = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri1.setConnection("****", "5435", "****", "****", "****")
uri1.setDataSource("" ,'(%s)' % sql1 , "geom","","gid")

ias = QgsVectorLayer(uri1.uri(),"ias","postgres",True)

if not ias.isValid():
    print "Layer %s did not load!" % ias.name()

sql2 = "select sub_id, gid, pop,tot_area, area_1, area_2, area_3, st_collectionextract(st_makevalid(geom),3)::geometry(MultiPolygon, 3047) as geom from dobrich_dobrich_s_subcatchments_result_m2_30"

uri2 = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri2.setConnection("****", "5435", "****", "*****", "*****")
uri2.setDataSource("", '(%s)' % sql2 , "geom","", "gid")

subs = QgsVectorLayer(uri2.uri(),"subs","postgres",True)

if not subs.isValid():
    print "Layer %s did not load!" % subs.name()

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([ias,subs],False)


i_res=processing.runalg('qgis:intersection',ias,subs,False,None)
```